# How to implement the exercise 15.5 in pil4?

Tags: lua

I am working on this exercise in pil4.

**Exercise 15.5**:

The approach of avoiding constructors when saving tables with cycles is too radical. It is
possible to save the table in a more pleasant format using constructors for the simple case, and to use
assignments later only to fix sharing and loops. Reimplement the function save (Figure 15.3, “Saving
tables with cycles”) using this approach. Add to it all the goodies that you have implemented in the previous
exercises (indentation, record syntax, and list syntax).

I have tried this with the code below, but it seems not to work on the nested table with a string key.

```
local function basicSerialize(o)
    -- number or string
    return string.format("%q",o)
end

local function save(name,value,saved,indentation,isArray)
    indentation = indentation or 0
    saved = saved or {}
    local t = type(value)
    local space = string.rep(" ",indentation + 2)
    local space2 = string.rep(" ",indentation + 4)
    if not isArray then io.write(name," = ") end
    if t == "number" or t == "string"  or t == "boolean" or t == "nil" then
        io.write(basicSerialize(value),"\n")
    elseif t == "table" then
        if saved[value] then
            io.write(saved[value],"\n")
        else
            if #value > 0 then
                if indentation > 0 then io.write(space) end
                io.write("{\n")
            end
            local indexes = {}
            for i = 1,#value do
                if type(value[i]) ~= "table" then
                    io.write(space2)
                    io.write(basicSerialize(value[i]))
                else
                    local fname = string.format("%s[%s]",name,i)
                    save(fname,value[i],saved,indentation + 2,true)
                end
                io.write(",\n")
                indexes[i] = true
            end
            if #value > 0 then
                if indentation > 0 then io.write(space) end
                io.write("}\n")
            else
                io.write("{}\n")
            end
            saved[value] = name
            for k,v in pairs(value) do
                if not indexes[k] then
                    k = basicSerialize(k)
                    local fname = string.format("%s[%s]",name,k)
                    save(fname,v,saved,indentation + 2)
                    io.write("\n")
                end
            end
        end
    else
        error("cannot save a " .. t)
    end
end

local a = { 1,2,3, {"one","Two"} ,5, {4,b = 4,5,6} ,a = "ddd"}
local b = { k = a[4]}
local t = {}
save("a",a,t)
save("b",b,t)
print()
```

And I got the wrong ouput.

a = {
    1,
    2,
    3,
    {
      "one",
      "Two",
    }
,
    5,
    {
      4,
      5,
      6,
    }
a[6]["b"] = 4
,
}

a["a"] = "ddd"

b = {}

b["k"] = a[4]

How could I make the text ' a[6]["b"] = 4 ' jump out of the table constructor?